# In Xcode is there a way to determine website traffic?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, web-traffic

I am wondering if there was some API or some kind of tool to use to determine a website traffic for Xcode.I need to track other websites traffic.

Comment: If there wasn't, there couldn't be websites that track traffic and make statistics. So the answer is "yes".

Comment: Where does Xcode come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve exact traffic information for a web site that you do not control, unless that web site publishes traffic information to a public location. Most web sites do not do this.

Some services are available online which will estimate web site traffic, such as Alexa. This data is not exact, and is only available as a paid service.